# How to drop incoming packets using TC

Tags: linux, iptables, packet, traffic, drop

I'm using tc to drop outgoing packets on a specified ethernet port. Is there a way to apply a similar loss of packets but not on the transmitting direction? I'd want to drop n% of packets that come into my system from a selected ethernet port.

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem loss 10%
```